# Google local app engine dev_appserver.py not running

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to get the Guestbook Application running on a Windows 10 machine. I have the followed the steps listed in the tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook), but when I try to run dev_appserver.py ./ (from Windows Power Shell) a new console briefly flashes and closes again, but it doesn't look like the web server starts. There is also no output message in the Power Shell console.

http://localhost:8080/ in my web browser shows no page (This site can’t be reached).

I have made sure .py extensions are run by python (not a text editor etc.)

I have checked the other posts with issues around starting the app server, but nothing matches this particular problem.

Comment: Try adding your powershell call to a try/catch like the example on the "Accessing the error record" section of this [blog](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell) so you can check any error that your python code is throwing and let me know what comes up.

Comment: Have you tried the method I described to get access to the error message?